# How do I find out which version of NodeJS NPM is using to build packages?

Tags: node.js

I'm using an npm module called [Hummus Renderer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hummusrenderer). It installs without any errors, but when I go to use it, I get this message:

```
module.js:355
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alexb/app/node_modules/hummusrenderer/node_modules/hummus/hummus.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

All of my Google searches told me to do `npm rebuild` since switching versions requires the C libraries to be compiled with new bindings.

The only way I can get this module to `require` is if I switch to `Node 0.10.40`. My suspicion is that the library is being built with the older bindings for some reason, while the `hummus` package claims to require `Node 0.12.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using hummus for the past s weeks. In my experience, it works fine with any version of Node from 0.10.x to latest 5.10.x

Since, hummusjs is a native node module, it is absolutely necessary to use the same node version while installing as well as using the node module.
Instead of node rebuild, I would simply prefer deleting the "hummus" folder from "node_modules" and doing an NPM install.